# Replace specific group of characters in match using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

So I want to match in string bellow, which will be formula for excell/ spreadsheet type cell, all addresses:  \w+\d+  , and change numbers only number part in them. `I want` to get following strings from original: `"= A2 + B2", "=A3+B3", "=A4+B4" ...`

I tried:

```
const a = "=A1 + B1"
for (let i = 0; i < 100 ; i++) {
    const b = a.replace(/\w+$(\d+)/g, String(i + 1));
    console.log(b)
}
```

and it gives result:

[image]

then if I do without $ before grouping () parentesis:

```
const a = "=A1 + B1"
for (let i = 0; i < 100 ; i++) {
    const b = a.replace(/\w+(\d+)/g, String(i + 1));
    console.log(b)
}
```

I get:

[image]

Comment: Given the input `"=A1 + B1"`, what result do you want?

Comment: So I want number (which in string is 1, but can be anything, like 24, 67, ) to be changed with index i + 1 in for loop.

Comment: So `"=A27 + B42"` becomes `="A1 + B1"`, `="A2 + B2"`, etc.?

Comment: yes, But the idea is that user insert  string `=A1 + B1`, and it will be adapted for differant cell adresses with this regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
const a = "=A1 + B1"
for (let i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
    const b = a.replace(/\b\w+\d+\b/g, function(match) {
        const num = match.match(/\d+/);
        const newNum = Number(num[0]) + i;
        return match.replace(/\d+/, newNum);
    });
    console.log(b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74982815/replace-specific-group-of-characters-in-match-using-regex#comment132322440_74982815), it sounds like you want 100 results, replacing the row numbers with 1, 2, 3, etc.

If so, capture the column number and use it in the replacement:

```js
function updateFormula(formula, i) {
    const result = formula.replace(
        /\b([A-Z]+)\d+\b/g,
        (m, column) => column + i
    );
    return result;
}

const formula = "=A42 + B27";
for (let n = 1; n <= 100; ++n) {
    const result = updateFormula(formula, n);
    // ...
}
```

Live Example (only doing 20 because the in-snippet console drops rows after a while):

```js
function updateFormula(formula, i) {
    const result = formula.replace(
        /\b([A-Z]+)\d+\b/g,
        (m, column) => column + i
    );
    return result;
}

const formula = "=A42 + B27";
for (let n = 1; n <= 20; ++n) {
    const result = updateFormula(formula, n);
    console.log(`${JSON.stringify(formula)} => ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
}
```

```css
.as-console-log {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, all answers are really great, but in code I decided to implement something similar to  Joan Lara Ganau answere.

```
const a = "=A1 + B1"
for (let i = 0; i < 100 ; i++) {
    const num = String(i+1);
    const b = a.replace(/\w+\d+/g, function(match) {
        return match.replace(/\d+/g, num)
    });
    console.log(b);
}
```

which produces :

[image]

Still don't know why we need \b, is it similar to ()?

Answer (score 0):

Just match the digits after a letter.

```js
const a = "=A1 + B1";
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  const b = a.replace(/(?<=[A-Z]+)\d+/g, i + 1);
  console.log(b);
}
```

Or you can use split the string to get the pattern, so you don't have to match it on every iteration.

```js
const a = "=A1 + B1"
const parts = a.split(/(?<=[A-Z]+)\d+/g);
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  const b = parts.join(i + 1);
  console.log(b);
}
```